# typeorm get tree structure with where and relations

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity `myobject` that is a tree entity and also contains relations to `comments`, `tags` and `user`. How can I query this entity and also get the relations?

```
@Entity('MyObject')
@Tree('closure-table')
export class MyObject {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @TreeChildren()
  childObjects: MyObject[];

  @TreeParent()
  parentObject: MyObject;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.objects)
  user: User;

  @OneToMany(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.object)
  comments: Comment[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Tags, (tags) => tags.objects)
  tags: Tags[];
}
```

My first non tree query was this:

```
this.objectRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('object')
      .leftJoin('object.tags', 'tags')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('object.childrenObjects', 'childrenObjects')
      .addSelect(['tags.id'])
      .leftJoinAndSelect('object.comments', 'comments')
      .where('object.user.id = :id', { id: userId })
      .getMany();
```

This gets me all I want but without the deep tree structure. I know that I can get the tree structure with `getManager().getTreeRepository(MyObject).findTrees().then()` but that is missing the relations and the where.

So how can I query for this data?

Answer (score 0):

At least the relational part can be done by using:

```js
findTrees({relations: ['tags']})
```

You'll get the nested tree structure with a tags property for each node containing the related objects.

Regarding the where part, I haven't figured out a solution yet, so I just traverse the tree recursively to get what I want.

UPDATE: after I tried to understood the closure table that is created I came up with a solution using the QueryBuilder:

```js
this.objectRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('object')
      .innerJoin("object_closure", "oc", "oc.id_descendant = object.id", )
      .leftJoin('object.tags', 'tags')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('object.childrenObjects', 'childrenObjects')
      .addSelect(['tags.id'])
      .leftJoinAndSelect('object.comments', 'comments')
      .where('object.user.id = :id', { id: userId })
      .getMany();
```